# Ubuntu 20.04 on capable machine runs very slow: Why?

Tags: 20.04, gnome-shell

I have Ubuntu 20.04 installed on my Lenovo ThinkPadP72, 6-core Xeon(R) E-2176M  CPU, 16GB of quality RAM, plenty of swap and drive space on a Samsung nvme SSD. Ubuntu has suddenly begun running like a slow and grunty pig: apps (e.g., Terminal, Text Editor) take a few seconds to launch, I can type and click faster than the system can respond). *Meh.* I throw myself upon the mercy of the debugging gurus, and place my faith in them.

**Insights**

- Slowdown occurs even when there is no process hogging the CPU.
- This occurs in different accounts on the machine.
- All the firmware tests on CPU, memory, keyboard, trackpad, motherboard, come up negative/roses.
- Firmware is up to date according to `fwupdate`.

---

````
%Cpu(s):  1.4 us,  1.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 97.1 id,  0.5 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :  15627.8 total,   4882.8 free,   5405.8 used,   5339.2 buff/cache
MiB Swap:  16384.0 total,  16384.0 free,      0.0 used.   8831.2 avail Mem 

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                           
   2452 root      20   0 1090928 576956 467380 S   6.9   3.6  14:46.54 Xorg                                                                                                                              
  10161 Lexible   20   0 2860008 342240 110284 S   5.3   2.1   4:01.12 WebExtensions                                                                                                                     
  10031 Lexible   20   0 4470748 979416 536852 S   4.3   6.1   7:52.96 firefox                                                                                                                           
  15417 Lexible   20   0  548928  54116  40532 S   4.3   0.3   0:05.58 gnome-terminal-                                                                                                                   
    220 root     -80   0       0      0      0 S   3.3   0.0   1:35.75 irq/12-i8042                                                                                                                      
   2737 Lexible   20   0 6052872 624652 131228 S   2.6   3.9   5:36.90 gnome-shell                                                                                                                       
   1743 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   1.3   0.0   1:00.86 nv_queue                                                                                                                          
      1 root      20   0  168420  12208   8328 S   0.7   0.1   0:15.69 systemd                                                                                                                           
  16754 Lexible   20   0   12252   4184   3252 R   0.7   0.0   0:00.07 top                                                                                                                               
     10 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.3   0.0   0:43.77 ksoftirqd/0                                                                                                                       
     18 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.3   0.0   0:18.62 ksoftirqd/1                                                                                                                       
     36 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.3   0.0   0:11.12 ksoftirqd/4                                                                                                                       
     60 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.3   0.0   0:18.04 ksoftirqd/8                                                                                                                       
    614 root     -50   0       0      0      0 S   0.3   0.0   0:04.32 irq/157-s-iwlwi                                                                                                                   
   1741 root     -50   0       0      0      0 S   0.3   0.0   0:44.09 irq/173-s-nvidi                                                                                                                   
   2915 Lexible   20   0  333060  44016  39468 S   0.3   0.3   0:04.08 kdeconnectd                                                                                                                       
   4447 Lexible   20   0 8970884 592408 223032 S   0.3   3.7   2:39.52 soffice.bin                                                                                                                       
   6017 Lexible   20   0  240792  31736  28628 S   0.3   0.2   0:02.26 kglobalaccel5                                                                                                                     
  12672 Lexible   20   0 2883272 545564 454532 S   0.3   3.4   0:34.60 Web Content                                                                                                                       
  13143 Lexible   20   0 2847920 450788 347364 S   0.3   2.8   1:19.65 Web Content                                                                                                                       
  14014 Lexible   20   0  990396 701696  94152 S   0.3   4.4   0:19.33 okular                                                                                                                            
      2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.03 kthreadd                                                                                                                          
      3 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 rcu_gp                                                                                                                            
      4 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 rcu_par_gp                                                                                                                        
      6 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H-kblockd                                                                                                              
      9 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 mm_percpu_wq                                                                                                                      
     11 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:11.48 rcu_preempt                                                                                                                       
     12 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.03 migration/0                                                                                                                       
     13 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 idle_inject/0                                                                                                                     
     14 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/0                                                                                                                           
     15 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/1                                                                                                                           
     16 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 idle_inject/1                                                                                                                     
     17 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.40 migration/1                                                                                                                       
     20 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker/1:0H-kblockd                                                                                                              
     21 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/2                                                                                                                           
     22 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 idle_inject/2                                                                                                                     
     23 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.41 migration/2                                                                                                                       
     24 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:13.98 ksoftirqd/2                                                                                                                       
     26 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker/2:0H-kblockd                                                                                                              
     27 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/3                                                                                                                           
     28 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 idle_inject/3                                                                                                                     
     29 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.42 migration/3                                                                                                                       
     30 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:11.68 ksoftirqd/3                                                                                                                       
     32 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker/3:0H-kblockd  ```
````

```
% free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           15Gi       5.2Gi       4.8Gi       1.1Gi       5.2Gi       8.7Gi
Swap:          15Gi          0B        15Gi
```

```
% sysctl vm.swappiness
vm.swappiness = 60
```

```
% ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions  
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 4 Lexible Lexible 4096 Mar 26 22:12 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 Lexible Lexible 4096 Jun  2 12:42 ..
drwxr-xr-x 5 Lexible Lexible 4096 Apr 25 11:18 dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com
drwxr-xr-x 4 Lexible Lexible 4096 Nov 13  2019 dynamicTopBar@gnomeshell.feildel.fr
```

```
% ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions 
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Apr 25 08:28 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 May 20 13:28 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 May 22 07:55 desktop-icons@csoriano
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov 13  2019 openweather-extension@jenslody.de
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Apr 24 18:20 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 May 20 13:28 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
```

```
$ sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
N2CET51W (1.34 )
```

Comment: If you log into a different user account (create one if you need to), does the same slowness occur?

Comment: Check for a firmware update for your Samsung nvme SSD.

Comment: Looks like you've stumped me on this one too! Sorry.